Question about field extension in Fulton's Algebraic Curves
I'm reading Fulton's Algebraic Curves, and here's an exercise 6.32 from Chapter 6, Section 5 (https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf).
Let $L=K(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ be a finite algebraic extension of $K$. Suppose $k\subseteq K$ is an algebraically closed subfield, and $V\subsetneq\mathbb{A}^n(k)$ is an algebraic set. Show that $L=K(\sum\lambda_ix_i)$ for some $(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)\in\mathbb{A}^n\setminus V$.
I think the result is obvious. Since $V$ is algebraic set, $\mathbb{A}^n\setminus V$ is dense in $\mathbb{A}^n$, by Theorem of the Primitive Element, we can choose $(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)\in\mathbb{A}^n\setminus V$. How should I rigorously write this proof?

Can you please say, which exercise exactly you are referring to?

It is not enough to just cite the theorem of the primitive element in it's standard form here. This is an improved version where we're picking a certain form of the generator. See the accepted answer here for a proof.
